Binding data from SQL Server to DDL in ASP.NET Core MVC project
I have an ASP.NET Core MVC project that has multiple forms. On one of the forms I want to have a drop down list full of agency names with the data being pulled from the SQL Server database.
The form is used for creating a record so the value should be null until the user selects the agency name, they want to have in the record. I get the following error when I try to load the form data is null. This method or property cannot be called on null values. I get the error message during rendering the view. I'm not sure if I called the wrong model in the controller or if this is even correct for what I'm trying to achieve.
Controller action method:
public IActionResult CreateNewRequest()
{
    string ConnectionString = connectionStrings.Get("RISSLinkConnectString");
    var list = new List<Agencies>();

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ag_Name FROM vw_AgencyDDB", conn))
    {
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        conn.Open();

        using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                list.Add(new Agencies
                             {
                                 AgencyName = rdr.GetString(0)
                             });
            }
        }

        conn.Close();
    }

    var model = new Request();
    model.AgNames = new SelectList(list, "ag_Name");

    return View(model); 
}

View:
@model Request
<h6>Equipment Request</h6>
<hr />
<body>
<form asp-action="CreateNewRequest" method="post" id="CreateRequest"> 
    <input type="submit" value="Create"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Cancel" asp-action="Index" />
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <table cellSpacing="0">

    <td>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.AgName, Model.AgNames)
                                        
    </td>                           
    </tr>
    </table>
</form>

<style>
    .body-container {
        /*remove the container default padding attribute*/
        /*padding-left: 0px !important;
                        padding-right: 0px !important;*/
        /*increase width as per your need*/
        max-width: 100%;
    }
</style>
</body>

Request Model:
public partial class Request
{
public SelectList AgNames { get; set; }
public int Rqkey { get; set; }

public string? Address1 { get; set; }

public string? Address2 { get; set; }

public string? Address3 { get; set; }

public string? AgId { get; set; }

public int? AgKey { get; set; }

public string? AgName { get; set; }

public DateTime? ApprovalDate { get; set; }

public byte? Approved { get; set; }

public string? ApprovedBy { get; set; }

public string? AuditComments { get; set; }

public DateTime? AuditDate { get; set; }

public string? City { get; set; }

public DateTime? Closed { get; set; }

public string? Comments { get; set; }

public int? Convictions { get; set; }

public string? CriminalActivity { get; set; }

public DateTime? DateAgencyReceived { get; set; }

public DateTime? DateAgencyReturned { get; set; }

public DateTime? DateDueBack { get; set; }

public DateTime? DateExtendedUntil { get; set; }

public DateTime? DateIssued { get; set; }

public DateTime? DateNeededFrom { get; set; }

public DateTime? DateNeededTo { get; set; }

public DateTime? DateReturnReceived { get; set; }

public int? Dbentry { get; set; }

public string? Disapproval { get; set; }

public byte? Extend { get; set; }

public DateTime? ExtendApprovalDate { get; set; }

public string? ExtendApprovedBy { get; set; }

public string? ExtendComments { get; set; }

public string? ExtendDisapproval { get; set; }

public string? ExtendReason { get; set; }

public string? FaxNumber { get; set; }

public byte? Intel { get; set; }

public string? Leccode { get; set; }

public string? Lecname { get; set; }

public string? Officer { get; set; }

public byte? Refer { get; set; }

public string? ReqId { get; set; }

public decimal? RequestAmt { get; set; }

public DateTime? RequestDate { get; set; }

public string? Results { get; set; }

public DateTime? ResultsDate { get; set; }

public string? ServiceType { get; set; }

public string? State { get; set; }

public string? Technician { get; set; }

public string? Useage { get; set; }

public string? VoiceNumber { get; set; }

public string? Zip { get; set; }

public DateTime? ZzCreationDate { get; set; }

public DateTime? ZzUpdateDate { get; set; }

public string? ZzUserCreated { get; set; }

public string? ZzUserLastUpdated { get; set; }

public int? AudioEnhancements { get; set; }

public int? VideoEnhancements { get; set; }

public string? County { get; set; }

public int? IndividualsLocated { get; set; }

public int? CasesResolved { get; set; }

public int? CasesProsecuted { get; set; }

public string? AgState { get; set; }

public int? RetrievedAv { get; set; }

public Guid? AgGuid { get; set; }

public DateTime? CourtDate { get; set; }

public int? ProductsDelivered { get; set; }

public int? ReqsToCourtroom { get; set; }

public int? OnSiteVisits { get; set; }

public int? NewEvidences { get; set; }

public int? NonCaseAvservices { get; set; }

public int? Consultations { get; set; }

public int? MediumsAnalyzed { get; set; }

public decimal? VolumeDataAnalyzedGb { get; set; }

public string? Email { get; set; }

public string? CaseNum { get; set; }

public string? CellNumber { get; set; }

public virtual ICollection<LoanedEquipment> LoanedEquipments { get; set; } = new List<LoanedEquipment>();

public virtual ICollection<ParticipatingAgency> ParticipatingAgencies { get; set; } = new List<ParticipatingAgency>();

public virtual ICollection<Seizure> Seizures { get; set; } = new List<Seizure>();

public virtual ICollection<Request> Requests { get; set; } = new List<Request>();

}

Your form is too long which I believe that you can exclude the fields other than your drop down list in the question. Meanwhile, can you share the complete error/exception message in the question? When and where did you get the error, during rendering the view?

yes it's during rendering the view and i edited the question

can you include full code for class Request
